# How to get the ID of active order by a user and the status of the order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Day,
I'm trying to get the list of recent active orders by a user, order ID and get the status of each of the active order in woocommerce, then print out any update in status of any of the orders. I have searched around for clues or snippet that would help me achieve this, but couldn't find one.

I was able to get how to count the number of order (using the below snippet)

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$numorders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $current_user->ID );
```

After searching on various blogs, i was able to this;

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );    
$order->get_status()
```

I'm really clueless how to combine this to print out the desired result (which is to have a list of notification update of any of the recent order(s) by a user.

The Goal of this is to create something like a mini order notification system where the result will look something like this;

#### Your ORDER NOTIFICATION

=> Your order with ID #24555 is being completed - 15-01-2019
=> Your order with ID #24234 is being completed - 13-01-2019
=> Your order with ID #24555 has been shipped - 10-01-2019
=> Your order with ID #24234 has been shipped - 10-01-2019
=> Your order with ID #12324 is being processed - 09-01-2019
[Maximum of 10 notification]

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to get all orders of a customer and then check the status of each order. Do you know how to to that?
Check here: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/

Comment: WooCommerce keep the order status in `wp_posts.post_status` table, and when ever you update the status or an order this fields get updated, so directly you cannot built this system, but there are 2 solutions number *one* which is inbuilt you can check the `wp_comments` table where all the order notes and status are logged as a comment, so you can filter out according to your need. *second* you can build your own table and logic where you will insert an order change as list it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @jasie for you response, I have gone through the link. The example on the page prints the message as a notice. How would I print the result so that I can have maximum of 10 notifications at ones and when order notification is more than 10, older notification should go away/be removed/deleted

Comment: @raunak-gupta Please can I have a snippet guide that I can work with? My pho level isn't too great yet

Comment: Set 'numberposts' => 10 returns maximum of 10 orders.

Comment: Thanks @jasie, trying it out now

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all orders of a customer, like so:

   `$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
       'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
       'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
       'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
   ) );`
2. Go through all orders and check the status of each order, like so:

   `$order->get_status( )`
3. Print out the ID and status and date as desired